# Another question concerning Lemma 1.12 of Wiles's proof of Fermat's Last Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, representation-theory, galois-theory, galois-representations

This is a follow-up on [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4343945/edit). So, at the risk of repeating myself, let me give some notation:

Let $k$ be a finite field of characteristic $p\neq 2$ (in fact, one only needs to consider the case $p\in\{3,5\}$), let $\Sigma$ be a finite set of primes containing $\infty$ and $p$, and

$$\rho_{0}:{\rm Gal}(\mathbb{Q}_{\Sigma}/\mathbb{Q})\rightarrow {\rm GL}_{2}(k)$$

an absolutely irreducible representation, meaning $\rho_{0}\otimes\overline{k}$ cannot be written as the direct sum of two one-dimensional subrepresentations, where $\mathbb{Q}_{\Sigma}$ is the largest Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ unramified outside the primes in $\Sigma$. Assume that if $\tau\in\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}_{\Sigma}/\mathbb{Q})$ is complex conjugation, then $\det(\rho_{0}(\tau))=-1$.
Then $\rho$ induces a projective representation

$$\tilde{\rho}_{0}:\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}_{\Sigma}/\mathbb{Q})\longrightarrow\operatorname{PGL}_{2}(k).$$

Assume in this case that the image of the projective representation is
$$\operatorname{image}(\tilde{\rho}_{0})\cong\left<s,r\mid s^{2}=r^{2}=(sr)^{2}=1\right>=(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{2}\text{.}$$
Assume further that $\rho_{0}|_{L}$ is absolutely irreducible, where $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}p})$.

The action of $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}_{\Sigma}/\mathbb{Q})$ on $k^{2}$ induces an action on $V_{\lambda}=\operatorname{Hom}(k^{2},k^{2})$, namely by conjugation. (What that $\lambda$ stands for is of no significance here.) Since $p\neq 2$, one has a direct sum of $k[\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}_{\Sigma}/\mathbb{Q})]$-modules

$$V_{\lambda}=W_{\lambda}\oplus k\text{,}$$

where $W_{\lambda}$ denotes the space of $\operatorname{trace}$-$0$ matrices and $k$ is the space of scalar multiplications.

Let $K_{1}$ be the splitting field of $\rho_{0}$ (i.e. $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}_{\Sigma}/K_{1})=\operatorname{ker}(\rho_{0})$), and
$$G:=\operatorname{Gal}(K_{1}/\mathbb{Q})=\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}_{\Sigma}/\mathbb{Q})/\operatorname{ker}(\rho_{0})=\operatorname{image}(\rho_{0}).$$

Since $\overline{\rho}_{0}$ has dihedral image, $\rho_{0}\otimes\overline{k}=\operatorname{Ind}_{H}^{G}(\chi)$ for some character $\chi$.

As [User:Mindlack](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/556825/mindlack) has generously explained to me in my previous question, $W_{\lambda}$ decomposes as a direct sum of $\operatorname{Gal}(k[\mathbb{Q}_{\Sigma}/\mathbb{Q}]$-modules:

$$W_{\lambda}\otimes\overline{k}=\delta\oplus\operatorname{Ind}_{H}^{G}(\chi/\chi')$$ where $\chi'$ is the quadratic twist of $\chi$ by any element of $G\setminus H$ and $\delta$ is the quadratic character $G\longrightarrow G/H$.

The goal is to show that for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and any Galois-stable subspace $X\subseteq W_{\lambda}\otimes\overline{k}$ there exists a $\sigma\in\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ so that

(i) $\rho_{0}(\sigma)\neq 1$,

(ii) $\sigma$ fixes $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^{n}})$ and

(iii) $\sigma$ has an eigenvalue $1$ on $X$.

I do not understand Wiles's argument, which runs as follows:

> If $\operatorname{image}(\rho_{0})\cong(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{2}$, we use the irreducibility of $\rho_{0}|_{L}$. If $\operatorname{Ind}(\chi/\chi')$ is irreducible over $\overline k$ (with $\chi'$ as in my previous question), then $W_{\lambda}\otimes\overline{k}$ is a sum of three distinct quadratic characters, none of which is the quadratic character associated to $L$, and we can repeat the argument by changing the choice of $H$ for the other two characters. If $X=\operatorname{Ind}^{G}_{H}(\chi/\chi')\otimes\overline{k}$ is absolutely irreducible then pick any $\sigma\in G\setminus H$. This satisfies (i) and can be made to satisfy (ii) if $\rho_{0}|_{L}$ is absolutely irreducible.

This is entirely unclear to me. First of all, he seems to make a case distinction where both cases are equal (namely in both cases $\operatorname{Ind}^{G}_{H}(\chi/\chi')$ is absolutely irreducible). My gut feeling tells me it should read *reducible* in the first case, but even then I don't understand the argument. Also, in the second case, why can one choose $\sigma$ so that it satisfies $(ii)$?

**REMARK**: I am fully aware that mathoverflow is usually the better place for questions related to the modularity theorem, but this is actually nothing more than straightforward linear algebra with a little Galois action.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure that's just a typo. It's clear from the context that it should say "if $\mathrm{Ind}_H^G(\chi/\chi')$ is reducible over $\overline k$", not irreducible. As you say, it's only in that case that $W_\lambda\otimes\overline k$ is a sum of three characters. He handles the case that $\mathrm{Ind}_H^G(\chi/\chi')$ is absolutely irreducible in the very next sentence.

Comment: I thought so too, but I don't understand what he means by "the other two characters"? Which of the three is the one which are the other two? To be honest, I don't get the entire argument.

Comment: Well, if it's reducible, then it splits as a direct sum of characters! The point is that when $\rho$ is an irreducible $2$-dimensional representation, there is a bijection between: 1) non-trivial characters $\chi$ such that $\rho\simeq\rho\otimes\chi$; 2) Quadratic extensions $H$ such that $\rho$ is induced from a character of $H$; 3) One dimensional subrepresentations of $W_\lambda = \mathrm{Sym}^2(\rho)\otimes\det\rho^{-1}$. Proving this equivalence is a fun exercise with Frobenius reciprocity.

Comment: Can you explain that in a little more détail?

Comment: In the reducible case, you have $W_\lambda = \delta \oplus\delta_1\oplus\delta_2$, where each of the characters is quadratic, with kernel $H_i$. By the equivalence I gave, you can show that $\rho$ is also induced from a character of each of the $H_i$'s. Moreover, if $\rho$ were induced from $L$, then $\rho|_L$ would be reducible. Since $L$ is the unique quadratic subfield of $\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)$, that means that $\sigma$ can be chosen to simultaneously fix $\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)$ and to satisfy $\delta_i(\sigma) = 1$ or $-1$. Moreover, the three characters are independent.

Comment: The point is that $X$ is an irreducible subrep of $W_\lambda$. So in this case, it has to be one of the three characters. And it's easy to choose $\sigma$ that: 1) fixes $\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)$, 2) satisfies $\delta_i(\sigma) = 1$ so that (iii) is satisfied and 3) satisfies $\delta_j(\sigma) = -1$ for some other character so that (i) is satisfied. To see why (i) is satisfied, by the equivalence, we have $\rho\simeq\rho\otimes\delta_j$, so if $\delta_j(\sigma) = -1$, then $\operatorname{tr}\rho(\sigma) = 0$. So $\tilde\rho(\sigma) $ can't be $1$, which has trace $2$.

Comment: could you give me a source (maybe a good textbook) on this, in particular on the part about the equivalence between characters so that $\rho=\rho\otimes\chi$ and the quadratic extensions that induce $\rho$? Also, why would $\rho_{L}$ be reducible if $\rho$ were induced by $L$? I am sorry if that question is stupid.

Comment: The equivalence is well-known, but doesn't seem to get taught much. I learnt (part of) it from Prop 11 of [this paper](https://mast.queensu.ca/~kani/papers/thetaCM2r.pdf), but it probably appears in Curtis and Reiner or some textbook like that. If you ask it on this site as a second question, I'd be happy to write an answer. I think I've lost count of the number of times I've mentioned it in comments here. For the second question, that's just Frobenius reciprocity. You have $1 \le (\rho, \mathrm{Ind}_H^G\chi) = (\rho|_H, \chi)$, so $\rho|_H$ contains $\chi$ as a subrepresentation.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Can you write it into an answer for this one?